# Pandas: group by specific date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to split the dataframe by specific dates and the cut-off level to be 31st of March. Meaning that everything that came before 31st of march should belong to a dataframe and everything after should belong to the next data frame and so on. The data looks like this:

```
                    c_name       date  revenue  t_rev
310260  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1997-01-31    3.628      0
296014  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1998-01-31    6.970      0
291248  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1998-05-06   10.429      0
287356  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1998-08-11   12.801      0
283720  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1998-11-10   18.419      0
279837  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1999-02-24   18.227      0
277333  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1999-04-27   22.304      0
274650  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1999-07-20   23.960      0
269885  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1999-10-26   26.890      0
265851  1-800 CONTACTS INC 2000-02-07   25.371      0
```

Expected output:

```
df1:
                        c_name       date  revenue  t_rev
    310260  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1997-01-31    3.628      0

df2:
                        c_name       date  revenue  t_rev
    296014  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1998-01-31    6.970      0

df3:
                        c_name       date  revenue  t_rev
    291248  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1998-05-06   10.429      0
    287356  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1998-08-11   12.801      0
    283720  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1998-11-10   18.419      0
    279837  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1999-02-24   18.227      0

df4: 

                         c_name       date  revenue  t_rev
    277333  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1999-04-27   22.304      0
    274650  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1999-07-20   23.960      0
    269885  1-800 CONTACTS INC 1999-10-26   26.890      0
    265851  1-800 CONTACTS INC 2000-02-07   25.371      0
```

My code so far is the following:

```
import pandas as pd


path = 'C:/Users/Adrian/Desktop/'
df = pd.read_csv(path + "trailing.csv", low_memory=False, usecols=[0, 3, 6])
df.rename(columns={'report_dte': 'date'}, inplace=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df = df.sort_values(["date"], ascending=True)
df['t_rev'] = 0

df2 = df.groupby("c_name")
counter = 0
for c_name, df_name in df2:
    counter += 1

    print(df_name.sort_values(['date'], ascending=True))
    print(len(df_name.index))
    if counter == 1:
        break
```

**@Josh Friedlander, @Jeril and @KeepAlive solutions work as expected. Thank you all!**

Comment: Better to use `loc` and assign new dfs than use `groupby`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Sorry to bother you, can you explain a bit more, please? Should I use loc to divide the dataframe into dataframes for each company? Or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: See Jeril's answer, but the second part - that's what I'd suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dint try running this code, but I guess it should work.

```
def getFiscalYear(dt):
    year = dt.year
    if dt.month<4: year -= 1
    return year

df['year'] = df['date'].apply(getFiscalYear)
df.groupby('year')
```

Make sure the 'date' column is of type `pd.datetime`. What we are doing here is, we are trying to create a column based on financial year, and grouping by based on that.

If you want to create a dataframe for each year, then you can iterate over the 'year' column and create new dataframe as you go.

```
df_dict = {}
for year in df['year'].unique():
    df_dict[year] = df[df['year' == year]]
```

Comment: Instead of `df[df['year' == year]]` use `df.loc[df['year'] == year]`

Answer (score 2):

A better way is with Pandas built-in `Period`:

```
df['year'] = df.date.dt.to_period('A-MAR')  # assigns years ending in March
dfs = [df.loc[df.year == year] for year in df.year.unique()]  
# gives list of dfs divided by year
```

Comment: Your code works as expected, but there is a small error that appears at the top: `A:/python project/trailing_accounts/read_excel.py:32: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead `

Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: read_excel is the name of the .py file. Initially, I was working with excel and not CSVs.  Changed it now to read_csv to match the problem at hand. 

Line 32 is this one: `df_name['year'] = df_name.date.dt.to_period('A-MAR')`

I changed the df to df_name because I first need to group the data by name and then do the grouping by year

Comment: is it sorted out?

Comment: yes, the problem is sorted out. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You're welcome :) I think my answer would be faster/more idiomatic than using `apply` like Jeril suggested but if performance is not a major concern, whatever works...

Answer (score 1):

What about doing

```
import datetime as dt

years        = range(1997, 2000 + 1)
df['date64'] = df.date.astype("datetime64")

for y,year in enumerate(years):
    min_date = dt.datetime(year    , 3, 31)
    max_date = dt.datetime(year + 1, 3, 31)

    globals()[f'df{y+1}'] = df.loc[
        (min_date < df.date64) & (df.date64 <= max_date)
    ].copy()
```

which has injected `df1`, `df2`, `df3` and `df4` in the global environment. Putting aside the discussion regarding if this is a good practice or not.

---

It is better to avoid playing directly inside the global environment like this: saving the truncated versions of `df` inside, say, a [dictionnary](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary) called `dfs`, is advocated:

```
dfs = {}
#...
    #...
    dfs[y+1] = df.loc[
        (min_date < df.date64) & (df.date64 <= max_date)
    ].copy()
```

or doing the same thing with a [list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list)

```
dfs = []
#...
    #...
    dfs.append(
        df.loc[(min_date < df.date64) & (df.date64 <= max_date)].copy()
    )
```

Comment: `Putting aside the discussion regarding if this is a good practice or not.` - I think it is really wrong practise, much better is dict

Comment: @Adrian does it work ? I am not able to test my code now.

Comment: @keepAlive so far the code in your solution does not work as expected, but that might be because of me.. I included in the original question how I tried to implement your solution.

Comment: @Adrian. This is because when you do `for element in dfs:print("each element ", element)`, you are not printing elements as such, but their associated key in the dictionnary. Do  `for key, element in dfs.items():print("each element ", key, element)`

Comment: @keepAlive Yes, I totally forgot that you need to iterate differently over dictionaries compared to lists. Thank you and sorry to have troubled you that much

Comment: If what I propose work as expected, maybe just editing your question to reflect that ? :) ... Thx :)

Comment: @keepAlive Yes, just did that :D